# Evaluate $\int\frac{\sqrt {25 - x^2}}{ x^4}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm pretty sure the method used is trig substitution. But I'm having trouble setting up and solving the problem.

Comment: Not just possible. Certain.

Comment: For that question I forget to include the square root. And I'm unfamiliar with this website, so I didn't know how to go back and change it. So I posted a new question with the sqrt included.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: WolframAlpha gives $$\int\dfrac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}{x^4}dx=-\dfrac{(25-x^2)^{3/2}}{75x^3}$$

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: As a rule, whenever you see $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$, the substitution $x=a\sin t$ is one of the possibilities worth trying. (In your case $x=5\sin t$.)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{x \equiv {1 \over u}}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\int{\root{25 - x^{2}} \over x^{4}}\,\dd x}
&=\int{\root{25 - 1/u^{2}} \over 1/u^{4}}\,
\pars{-\,{\dd u \over u^{2}}}
=-\int u\root{25u^{2} - 1}\,\dd u
\\[3mm]&=-\,\half\int\root{25u^{2} - 1}\,\dd\pars{u^{2}}=-\,{\pars{25u^{2} - 1}^{3/2} \over 75}
=-\,{\bracks{25\pars{1/x}^{2} - 1}^{3/2} \over 75}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large -\,{\root{25 - x^{2}} \over 75x^{3}}} + \pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice minimalist approach.

Comment: @Alraxite Thanks. Yes, short.

Answer (score 0):

Subsititute $\theta=\sin^{-1} \dfrac{x}5\implies \dfrac{d\theta}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}$, so we get,

\begin{align}
\\\\\\&\int\frac{\sqrt{25-x^2}}{x^4}dx
\\=&\int\frac{25-x^2}{x^4}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}d\theta
\\=&\int \dfrac{25-25\sin^2 \theta}{625\sin^4\theta}d\theta
\\=&\dfrac{1}{25}\int\dfrac{\cos^2 \theta}{\sin^4\theta}d\theta
\\=&\dfrac{1}{25}\int\cot^2\theta \csc^2\theta d\theta
\end{align}

Now subsitute $u=\cot \theta$ to finish.